# Checked data-binding is not working for an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, knockout.js

I am working on a knockout code, following are the conditions:

1. I have a set of primary shipping methods and each of them has a secondary shipping method.
2. based on whether a primary shipping method is chosen and a few other flag values, the secondary method gets checked with data-bind checked.

Following is the JSP code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: checkout.cart.order.productsShippingMethods() -->          
    <div class="row">
         <input type="radio" name="shipmethod" data-bind="value: $data.methodId, checked: $parent.checkout.shippingMethod,click: $parent.checkout.setSecondaryShippingMethod($data.methodId)" value="StandardResidential">
         <strong data-bind="text: $data.displayName"> </strong>
    </div>
<!--  ko foreach: $data.secondaryShippingMethods -->
    <div class="secDiv">
        <!-- ko if: ($parentContext.$parent.checkout.cart.order.isLiftGateDeliveryMandatory() !== true && $parent.methodId === 'StandardResidential'  && ($parentContext.$parent.checkout.cart.order.isLiftGateDeliveryRecommended() !== true))-->
            <div class="row">
                <label class="checkbox mt0">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data.methodId, checked: $parentContext.$parent.checkout.secShippingMethods()[0]">
                    <strong data-bind="text: $data.displayName"> </strong>
                </label>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Following is the JS associated with it:

```
self.setSecondaryShippingMethod = function(shipMethod){
        if(shipMethod === "Ground"){
            if(self.secShippingMethods !== "GoundSecondary"){
                self.secShippingMethods([]);
            }
            if(self.cart.order.isLiftGateDeliveryMandatory() == true || self.cart.order.isLiftGateDeliveryRecommended() == true){
                self.secShippingMethods([]);
                self.secShippingMethods.push("GroundSecondary");
            }
        }
        if((shipMethod === "Premium") || (shipMethod === "Platinum")){
            self.secShippingMethods([]);
            self.secShippingMethods.push("RemoteLocation");
        }
    };
```

Now the problem is, whenever I click on any of the primary methods, all the secondary methods are triggered to `checked` `data-bind` and `checked` becomes true for all secondary methods checkboxes. I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: I think you want `checked: $parentContext.$parent.checkout.secShippingMethods`

Comment: I am not able to add an image to show how this is behaving

Comment: @MichaelBest secShippingMethods is an array and the value of secondary shipping methods get filled up in it. So the parenthesis and [0] is required I guess. I'm able to cross verify the values in Knockout debugger. they are coming as expected but `checked` binding is still behaving differently. I guess I'm missing out on something.

Comment: Which observable is storing which methods they've checked?

Comment: @MichaelBest Ohh I guess there's a confusion, there's a `methodId` in each of the `productsShippingMethods` and `secondaryShippingMethods`

Comment: Try what I suggested. Let me know how it works.

Comment: @MichaelBest didn't work although values are getting updated in `secShippingMethods` checked binding is not working anymore. probable reason is that `secShippingMethods` is an array and the values stored are in [0] element.

Comment: you said "I have a set of primary shipping methods and each of them has a secondary shipping method" but you have a foreach loop suggesting a shipping method has an array of secondary shipping methods. so maybe you are looking for the with binding instead of the foreach binding.

Comment: What version of Knockout are you using?

Comment: @MichaelBest v3.4.0

Comment: Another thing I noticed. You have `checked` and `click` bindings for your radio buttons. But you shouldn't do this. Instead set up a subscription to `shippingMethod` that updates `secShippingMethods` when it changes.

Comment: Read up on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html In any case, I don't think anyone can really help you unless you produce a complete example (in jsfiddle maybe).

Answer (score 0):

my solution simpler use attr

```
var dta=$('input this or whatever').attr('data-bind') // all data given
alert(dta); //"value: $data.methodId, checked: $parent.checkout.shi
```

or if( checked attr('checked')==true){} like this